# Mirroring won't fail back

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

Got an interesting mirroring issue.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Server A mirrors 8 databases to Server B ideally.  Right now the 8 databases are principal on Server B (otherwise healthy).  When I try to manually fail a database over to Server A, it fails over, then a few seconds later it fails back to Server B.

Error logs don't indicate anything other than reporting the failover and (unwanted) failback.  Only way I can think of to keep the databases live on Server A is to manually stop Server B, which would kill HA entirely.

Anybody seen this happen to them?

Comment: Please post your setup (HA with witness?) and the logs

Comment: There are a lot of things that can cause mirror failover...resources being overworked, network issues (bad nic in server A possibly), things like that, heck it is possible there is even a job that automatically fails the db's back over to server B if server B is running.   Do you know what sort of queries or processes were running on Server A when this happened?

Comment: `Error logs don't indicate anything other than reporting the failover and (unwanted) failback.` There has to be something logged. Did you check windows event viewer - system and application logs ? Can you post the exact error messages with error numbers ?

Comment: Hi all... mystery was solved.  Turns out there was a job that runs every 5 seconds that, if not all of the 8 databases on this server was principal on Server A, it would fail them all over to Server B.  Kinda a crude form of an AG.  Lesson learned: if it doesn't make sense, look for a job.  Thanks all!